# Can I install a SATA-II hybrid hard-drive in HP Pavilion dv6000 laptop?

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion, hybrid-storage

I have an HP Pavilion dv6000 laptop. It's an Intel processor model. Originally had 2GB DDR2 RAM - which I later upgraded to 3GB. It's hard-drive is Western Digital [WD1600BEVS](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/search/1/a_id/5391#)-60RST0. The drive height is 0.37 in / 9.4 mm.

Since I don't have any plans to shell out a 1000 bucks on new laptop, I want to upgrade the hard-drive of the laptop (in-fact, the only option left to increase its performance). I am planning for **Seagate Momentus XT ST93205620AS** or **Seagate Momentus XT ST95005620AS**, which are hybrid drives. As per this post on [hp.com](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-e-g-Windows-8/HP-Pavilion-dv6000-Hard-Drive-Upgrade-Question/td-p/450127), the Intel version should support 7200 RPM drives. But what about hybrid drives? Will the machine support a hybrid-drive or should I stick to a 7200 RPM drive?

In short, I am looking for a fastest possible drive that can be installed in my laptop, preferably with 32MB buffer - except for SSD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have installed a Seagate ST1000LM014 SSHD (1TB, 5400RPM, 64MB Cache, 6Gb/s, 8GB SSD), a SATA-II drive. And its working fine till now.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't mind any hard drive you use in that model being restricted to SATA-I specifications, you will be all right.  Will that drive work?  Sure.  Will it work at SATA-II specifications?  Nope.

Comment: Thanks Bon. Are the connectors for the 2 drives of different shapes/sizes?

Comment: Found the answer - no difference in connectors. I hope I can atleast plug in a SATA-II drive with more buffer, compared to 8MB only in current drive. Am I right?

Comment: The increased buffer is not due to the improved SATA-II specifications, but rather the improved drive.  You should benefit from the 32mb buffer without issue.

Comment: Thanks Bon. In that case, I am good to go with a Hybrid drive.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problems upgrading to a hybrid drive, furthermore it's mentioned in the second reply in the thread that the OP could try a hybrid. However, it's important to say that the SSHD architecture is specific because it blends HDD capacity with SSD speeds by placing traditional rotating platters, and a small amount of high-speed flash memory on a single drive. It has a certain amount of fast storage (cache) for commonly accessed files, which means that the files within this cache are accessed at SSD speeds and everything else is accessed at standard HDD speeds.

For the replacement procedure you can take a look at this guide from the manufacturer:

http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00763252